# How to properly list all tables for this particular structure in Server SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this structure as:

```
-Server
   -Databases
       -System Databases <- I do not want this
          - master
          - model
          - msdv
          - tempdb
       -Database Snapshots <- Neither this
       -DB1 (a database) <- I want the info in here
          - Databases Diagrams
          - Tables <- Name of tables, size and rows
          - Views
          - etc...
       -DB2              <- and here
       -etc..            <- and All of that
```

I would like to list all the tables inside all these DB1, DB2... to gather information such as table_name, number of rows, size, etc.

I have initially tried this:

```
SELECT
    d.name
    ,d.create_date
FROM
    sys.databases d
WHERE 
    d.name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
```

which lists me the databases (DB1, DB2...) now...

If for example I wanted the tables of a single DB I would do:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    DB1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
```

and **it will list them all** but how do I get, for each DB, the information below?

- Name of the tables
- Number of rows
- Size

The problem that I'm currently having is that my queries only fetch on System Databases I do onot know how to do the above

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your "structure" doesn't look like a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is not a table, its how it is organized. Its a databse with user defined databases inside.

Comment: Are you looking for sys.objects? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @NevilleKuyt not quite, I just want to list all the tables of those DB. All I get so far is the ones inside the System Databases when I want the tables from DB1, DB2, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE ( 
  DatabaseName sysname, 
  SchemaName sysname, 
  TableName sysname 
);

INSERT INTO @Tables (DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName) 
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?'', s.name, t.name from [?].sys.tables t inner join [?].sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id';


SELECT 
    *
FROM
    @Tables t
WHERE 
    t.DatabaseName NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
```

This gets my desired result i.e:

```
DB1 - dbo - tableName1
DB1 - dbo - tableName2
...
DB2 - dbo - tableName1
```

and so on for every table in the server

Thank you all for your time